# How can I boost WiFi data transfer rate?

Tags: wifi, file-transfer

I have a wireless router that clients are using to have internet and file transfer in our company. The link speed is 54Mbit within all clients.

But it seems that is impossible to exceed ~8 mbit which equals around 1MB/s

How can there be that high link speed and only that poor transfer rate?

Ps. I am not interested in investing for a 802.11n wireless network. 802.11g is fine too!

Comment: How many clients are there. As many other posts have indicated, WiFi is a shared medium so that 54Mbps "high link speed" is shared amongst all your clients.

Comment: You may also have some interference with other devices maybe, like microwaves or other WiFi routers.

Comment: Here's answer I wrote regarding a similar question... [Wireless to Wireless Transfer Slow on a Linksys-WRT54GL](http://serverfault.com/questions/50877/wireless-to-wireless-transfer-slow-on-a-linksys-wrt54gl/330324#330324)

Comment: Are you running in G-only? If not, that is most likely contributing to the problem. See the following: http://serverfault.com/questions/322824/slowest-wireless-client-dictates-the-connection-quality-of-all-others/322866#322866

Comment: I don't want to sound like an arse, but the easiest way to fix slow wifi rate is to plug the computers into a physical switch. As others are alluding to, the fewer clients on your WiFi the higher the speed will be.

Comment: Have to agree with Mark, if speed is important ditch wireless. Also, 8mbit would be 0.008 bits per second. I think you mean Mbps (mega bits per second). Worse, you seem to think that Mb are MB (mega bytes). Capitalization makes a big difference in these units, put some effort into it.

Comment: To clarify: 8Mbit = 1MB/s (1mb/s is 1 Mbit). To reiterate what others have said -- you're only going to see significant speed improvements by going with a faster wireless technology (802.11n), hard-wiring, or moving closer to the wireless source (either the device itself or the end unit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shutdown everyone except the farthest wifi-based workstation, disable 802.11b on the WAP, then try testing the bandwidth from the wifi-based workstation and a wired target: you are not going to get any better speed than this without some changes.

1. What make / model WAP are you using?  Does it have more than one antenna?
2. Can you deploy a second WAP to alleviate congestion on the first WAP?

54Mbps is **only** theoretical, the best throughput I can recall having on Linksys / Netgear 802.11g equipment is ~3.5MB/s and that was only one client, so depending on your load you're not too far off.